# How to fix SQL Syntax error for MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload .csv file data to MySQL table through web form interface. After searching scripts I got one to do the job, but it is giving SQL syntax error during execution. Here I am giving that particular code snippet as of now, but if required I would give the full code.

```
            if($this->table_exists)
            {
              $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).
                     "' INTO TABLE '".$this->table_name.
                     "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_separate_char).
                     "' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char).
                     "' ESCAPED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_escape_char).
                     "' ".
                     ($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "")
                     ."('".implode("','", $this->arr_csv_columns)."')";
              $res = @mysql_query($sql);
              $this->error = mysql_error();
            }
```

During execution, it is throwing the following error:

**Errors**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''temp_18_04_2015_05_44_00' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\' ' at line 1
```

The gererated SQL command is as follows

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/phpFzT3qc' 
INTO TABLE 'temp_18_04_2015_06_06_37' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
IGNORE 1 LINES ('SLNO','NAME')
```

I am a novice programmer, so I am not being able to get the error...

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `mysql_` API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`.

Comment: Can you share the SQL command?

Comment: @Jens. hope I have already shared the SQL command. Anything else you are asking about?

Comment: I mean the generated SQL command without the php function. So print out `$sql` and share it.

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/phpFzT3qc' INTO TABLE 'temp_18_04_2015_06_06_37' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\' ESCAPED BY '\\' IGNORE 1 LINES ('SLNO','NAME')  @Jens

Comment: Please add it to the question using the edit function. Not as comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to remove the single quotes around the table Name:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name).
                     "' INTO TABLE ".$this->table_name.
                     " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_separate_char).
                     "' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char).
                     "' ESCAPED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_escape_char).
                     "' ".
                     ($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "")
                     ."('".implode("','", $this->arr_csv_columns)."')";
```

If you use the single qoutes it is a string and not a table Name. to escape table names you have to use backticks.

For more Information about the Syntax of `LOAD DATA INFILE` see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Jens, I think single quotes are allowed as per SQL syntax. I have seen that while running commands in PHPMyadmin.

Comment: @samlancer Single quotes are allowed. that is correct. But only to use it with static strings not with table or column names.

Comment: No, Jens. I tried after removing the single quotes around the table name, but it did not work. Can you suggest another running script available in web which can import .csv file to MYSQL database using PHP?

Comment: Sorry! It is showing Errors: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SLNO','NAME')' at line 1 . I beg your excuse, I put it here again. @Jens

Comment: The new generated SQL command is LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/phpsa08CZ' INTO TABLE temp_18_04_2015_06_18_55 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\' ESCAPED BY '\\' IGNORE 1 LINES ('SLNO','NAME') @Jens

Comment: @samlancer I guess that are the column names. Remove the single quotes too.

Comment: Strange! The earlier error gone, but now it is showing Errors : Access denied for user 'dchcov5r_demo'@'localhost' (using password: YES). How was it working earlier? @Jens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75567/discussion-between-jens-and-samlancer).